# A human settled alien planet where even children are issued blasters and must be good at using them to kill constantly attacking lifeforms

Tags: story-identification

My father told me he read this story when he was young (I think). He was born in 1935 and is passed away now. He didn't remember the title or author but it impressed him.

Comment: How will you recognize a correct answer?

Comment: It somehow reminds me of the Catachan planet in the Warhammer 40000 universe. Anything and everything is out to eat you.

Comment: @Clockwork 40k's Catachan almost certainly would have drawn inspiration from Harry Harrison's "Deathworld" series, which appears to be the one Mark is describing.

Comment: @fectin "... even children are issued blasters and must be good at using them..." would seem to be pretty unique. You must admit that would be a very good clue. That is the "killer" clue!

Comment: I immediately thought this was Heinlein's Red Planet (1949), which was lightly formative for many people your father's age, so "impressed him" is the killer clue. Deathworld fits the word "issued" better. It's a less good fit for a number of other stories too

Comment: Thanks for this question (and thanks to PG for making it publicly available)! I just found an excellent sci-fi read on a random Thursday morning!

Comment: @fectin It was formative for myself as well (born 1961). I will never forget Heinlein's description of sleeping in the shelter of a plant with large leaves. Mental picture it painted.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I expect this is probably [*Deathworld*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2127) (1960) by Harry Harrison.  The protagonist is Jason dinAlt, a mildly psychic gambler/con man who is recruited by Kerk, a citizen of the titular planet (actually called Pyrrus) to win a bunch of money to buy guns, and who is forced to flee to Pyrrus to escape the casino bosses who come after him.

Pyrrus is indeed extremely hostile, with all the flora and fauna constantly evolving to better attack the human colonists.  All the colonists always wear guns in power holsters that can put their gun in their hand in a fraction of a second.  Jason is a bit of a quick-draw expert, but is no match for them.  Children are taught to use weapons from a very young age, and in fact Jason is put in with some very young children for remedial weapons training.

The full text is [available from Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/28346).

Comment: Serialized in six 1960 issues of *Astounding* (January through June). Use @DavidW's ISFDB page to see links to individual issues ISFDB pages; each issue page has a link to a downloadable PDF version of the issue!

Comment: Totally this. Just from that short description I recognized the book- and the description fits it to a T.

Comment: Deathworld is available at https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/28346 from the Jan, Feb and March issues of Astounding. Apparently the copyright was not renewed on the magazine version. The British edition of Astounding for Apr to June carried the story also (see isfdb.org).

Comment: @DavidW This must be it. Thank you so much. Now I can read it too. It came out one year before I was born! Love Harry Harrison.

Comment: @WHG thanks for the link!

Comment: "Kerk", huh?  I was gonna say they ripped the name (with a vowel-change) off the original captain of the Enterprise, but it looks like this came first, by only 6 years; I wonder if Roddenberry was a fan?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman "Kerk" is the Dutch word for "church", "kirk" is the Scottish spelling of the same. As such, the presence of either spelling as part of a name is an unremarkable occurrence, and there's hence zero reason to believe that this story is linked with Star Trek in any way shape or form.